# Dynamically populate an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the following 6 strings.

```
user1 A
user2 B
user4 C
user2 D
user1 E
```

I need to create a Dictionary like:

```
arr['user1'] => ['A', 'E']
arr['user2'] => ['B', 'D']
arr['user4'] => ['C']
```

How to do this in PHP?

Comment: [There are _five_ strings!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_eSwq1ewsU)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work...

```
$arr = array();

foreach($lines as $line) {
    list($user, $letter) = explode(" ", $line);
    $arr[$user][] = $letter;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/VkMaT8cb).

Answer (score 3):

This is what you can do:

```
$strings = array(
    'user1 A',
    'user2 B',
    'user4 C',
    'user2 D',
    'user1 E',
);

$arr = array();

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $values = explode(" ", $string);
    $arr[$values[0]][] = $values[1];
}
```

Comment: good solution as long as you're guaranteed valid input in a fixed format

Comment: So how can we access the value of the array's name $arr[$values[0]] aka array['user1'], array['user2'], .... after it's populated using a foreach loop?

Comment: This is how I accessed the nested array's name: `foreach($arr as $a => $value) {
echo 'array name:'.$a.'\n';
}`, but what about searching for a match eg: `$username == $a` not in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming $string is the string of values you have:

```
$mainArr = array();
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $elements = explode(' ', $line);
    $mainArr[$elements[0]][] = $elements[1];
}
print_r($mainArr);
```

Assuming $mainArr is the array of values, and you already have the array:

```
$newArr = array(); // Declaring an empty array for what you'll eventually return.
foreach ($mainArr as $key => $val) { // Iterate through each element of the associative array you already have.
    $newArr[$key][] = $val; // Pop into the new array, retaining the key, but pushing the value into a second layer in the array.
}
print_r($newArr); // Print the whole array to check and see if this is what you want.
```

You'll want to look at multidimensional arrays in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: The question is assuming a string input, not a multi-dimensional array, so you'll need to explode or parse it first

Comment: @soulkphp Gotcha. From the question, I was thinking those values were inside of an array already. If not, I've added a way for parsing that string into an array.